# Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /home/rails/webapp/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException) running docker build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler

I've been running into this problem whenever I try to run `docker build -t ruby-app .`, I get the following error:

```
Step 6/8 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Running in daa149748210
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /home/rails/webapp/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
#Dockerfile    
FROM ruby:latest
ENV HOME /home/rails/webapp
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
WORKDIR $HOME
ADD Gemfile* $HOME/
RUN bundle install
ADD . $HOME
CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My bundler versions installed on my machine are the following:

```
➜ gem list bundler          

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.1.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

And my Gemfile.lock was generated by the following versions of Ruby and Bundler

```
#Gemfile.lock    
RUBY VERSION
ruby 2.7.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
2.1.4
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try `docker pull ruby` and see if that helps things?  If I run the `ruby:latest` image right now I get Ruby 2.7.1p83, but you're getting an error message from a Ruby 2.6.0 build, which might have older Rubygems and/or Bundler.

Comment: Since the Bundler 2.1 series removed all notions of compatibility with anything (Bundler 2.1.4 will not run a Gemfile.lock `BUNDLED WITH 2.1.3`) putting in the `RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4` as suggested is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add

`RUN gem install bundler`

before you invoke `bundler`, that should do the trick.

Comment: If you want to install a specific version, it's `RUN gem install bundler:1.17.3` for e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo gem install bundler:2.1.2 -n /usr/local/bin` before you invoke